# get downloaded file from URL and Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

```
  string uri = "https://sometest.com/l/admin/ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q";

  string filePath = "D:\\Data\\Name";

  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFile(uri, (filePath + "/" + uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/'))));

/// filePath + "/" + uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/')) = "D:\\Data\\Name//ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q"
```

Accesing the entire ( string ) `uri`, a .ical file will be automatically downloaded... The file name is `room113558101.ics` ( not that this will help ).

How can I get the file correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()`?

Comment: What of that URL are you deeming is a filename as from / onwards contains a "?" which most certainly isnt valid

Comment: @BugFinder when accesing the uri, a file is auttomaticaly downloaded...

Comment: `uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/')))` == `ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q` BugFinder's point is that the "?" in that is invalid to add to your file name.

Comment: this is what you end up using for filename "ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q" it contais '?' which is not allowed character in filenames.I believe you only need "ical.html" thus you need to trim the "?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q" part of the string

Comment: `DownloadFile("D:\\Data\\Name\\ical.html")` should download the ical.html. But `DownloadFile("D:\\Data\\Name\\ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q")` must not open ical.html and pass an argument to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your filepath in a wrong way, which results in invalid file name (`ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q`). Instead, use `Uri.Segments` property and use last path segment (which will be `ical.html` in this case. Also, don't combine file paths by hand - use `Path.Combine`:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://sometest.com/l/admin/ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q");
var lastSegment = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
string directory = "D:\\Data\\Name";
string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, lastSegment);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(uri, filePath);
```

To answer your edited question about getting correct filename. In this case you don't know correct filename until you make a request to server and get a response. Filename will be contained in response Content-Disposition header. So you should do it like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://sometest.com/l/admin/ical.html?t=TD61C7NibbV0m5bnDqYC_q");
string directory = "D:\\Data\\Name";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();  
// make a request to server with `OpenRead`. This will fetch response headers but will not read whole response into memory          
using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri)) {
    // get and parse Content-Disposition header if any
    var cdRaw = webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"];
    string filePath;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cdRaw)) {
        filePath = Path.Combine(directory, new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition(cdRaw).FileName);
    }
    else {
        // if no such header - fallback to previous way
        filePath = Path.Combine(directory, uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1]);
    }
    // copy response stream to target file
    using (var fs = File.Create(filePath)) {
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accesing the entire  uri, a .ical file will be downloaded, not an .html file

Comment: @FlorinM. well your question is about illegal characters in path error, nothing about what type of file is being downloaded.

Comment: @FlorinM. I've edited answer with additional info about that.